# R Max of Same Date, Previous Date, and Previous Hour Value

Tags: r, datetime, max, min

A couple basic data manipulations.  I searched with different wordings and couldn't find much.

I have data structured as below.  In reality the hourly data is continuous, but I just included 4 lines as an example.

```
start <- as.POSIXlt(c('2017-1-1 1:00','2017-1-1 2:00','2017-1-2 1:00','2017-1-2 2:00'))
values <- as.numeric(c(2,5,4,3))
df <- data.frame(start,values)
df

            start     values
1 2017-01-01 01:00:00      2
2 2017-01-01 02:00:00      5
3 2017-01-02 01:00:00      4
4 2017-01-02 02:00:00      3
```

I would like to add a couple columns that:
1) Show the max of the same day.
2) Show the max of the previous day.
3) Show the value of one previous hour.

The goal is to have an output like:

```
MaxValueDay <- as.numeric(c(5,5,4,4))
MaxValueYesterday <- as.numeric(c(NA,NA,5,5))
PreviousHourValue <- as.numeric(c(NA,2,NA,4))
df2 <- data.frame(start,values,MaxValueDay,MaxValueYesterday,PreviousHourValue)  
df2

            start     values MaxValueDay MaxValueYesterday PreviousHourValue
1 2017-01-01 01:00:00      2           5                NA                NA
2 2017-01-01 02:00:00      5           5                NA                 2
3 2017-01-02 01:00:00      4           4                 5                NA
4 2017-01-02 02:00:00      3           4                 5                 4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`, `magrittr`, and `lubridate` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  within(MaxValueDay <- sapply(as.Date(start), function (x) max(df$values[which(x==as.Date(start))]))) %>%
  within(MaxValueYesterday <- MaxValueDay[sapply(as.Date(start)-1, match, as.Date(start))]) %>%
  within(PreviousHourValue <- values[sapply(start-hours(1), match, start)])

#                 start values MaxValueDay MaxValueYesterday PreviousHourValue
# 1 2017-01-01 01:00:00      2           5                NA                NA
# 2 2017-01-01 02:00:00      5           5                NA                 2
# 3 2017-01-02 01:00:00      4           4                 5                NA
# 4 2017-01-02 02:00:00      3           4                 5                 4
```